# Unable to modify more than one string in bat file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to read all files and replace substrings in it.
when I execute bat file only first command executes 
i.e. `SET modified=!string:%oldstr1%=%newstr1%!`

rest 2 commands dont execute

```
SET modified=!string:%oldstr2%=%newstr2%!

SET modified=!string:%oldstr3%=%newstr3%!
```

CODE IS AS FOLLOWS

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set LOCATION=D:\CODE_temp\RUNTIME_DATA\

set OUTTEXTFILE=test_out.txt

set oldstr1=workflow.actions

set newstr1=process.activities

set oldstr2=CallWorkflow

set newstr2=CallProcess

set oldstr3=SetWorkflowVariable

set newstr3=SetProcessVariable


FOR /r %LOCATION% %%x IN (*.txt) do (

FOR /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ('"type %%x"') do (

SET string=%%A

SET modified=!string:%oldstr1%=%newstr1%!

SET modified=!string:%oldstr2%=%newstr2%!

SET modified=!string:%oldstr3%=%newstr3%!

echo !modified! >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
)

del %%x

copy %OUTTEXTFILE% %%x

del %OUTTEXTFILE%

echo location  %%x >> Enosh_log.txt

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, what do you expect?
You always replace a string in the original `string` and set it to the `modified` variable.
So you always overwrite the same variable.

Better you should use something like this

```
FOR /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ('"type %%x"') do (
  SET "string=%%A"
  SET "modified=!string:%oldstr1%=%newstr1%!"
  SET "modified=!modified:%oldstr2%=%newstr2%!"
  SET "modified=!modified:%oldstr3%=%newstr3%!"
   >> %OUTTEXTFILE% echo !modified!
)
```